# How do you delete the current (but not all) plots in the RStudio plotting device?

Tags: r, rstudio

How do you delete the current (but not all) plots in the RStudio plotting device?

`dev.off()` will remove all plots, but what if I just want to remove one? I don't want to have to press that red 'x' button because I want to remove one plot without pressing a button.

Comment: Under the Plots tab there is Remove Plot that will remove whichever plot is shown in the plot window.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In R, you would just use `dev.new()` before each plot, so you `dev.off()` to only clear the last plot.

In RStudio, you can use `x11()`, `windows()` or `quartz()` (depending on your device) before each plot. Then call `dev.off()` to clear last plot. You can also use `dev.set()` to choose specific plots that way.

If your question is specifically asking to delete the last plot within the same RStudio window (rather than making new windows), not sure if it's possible, since RStudio treats that window as one device. An idea would be to look at a way to call the C++ function `removePlot()` in the RStudio project.

I found in the [Github repository for RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/9822a771429a865e898a0dc398528d8869f171f1/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionPlots.cpp#L81) the C++ code:

```
display.removePlot(display.activePlotIndex());
```

You could output the plots and manage the files that way.