# How to clear only specific plots from window in R?

Tags: r, plot, window, rstudio

To clear all plots in R window we just need to use `dev.off()`. But let's assume that we have three plots in our R window and I want to empty only the second one. I searched for some command to achieve that, however I wasn't able to find any.

Thanks for your answer!

I didn't mention side by side plots - more something like these situation in which I have:

In first window
[image]

If I now use right arrow I will have plot in second window and so on..

Comment: *"Three plots in our R window"* sounds like you're using `par(mfrow=..)`, `layout(..)`, or a similar multi-plotting method in R. If that's the case, then ... I believe you cannot remove just one of them, you need to recreate the other plots and just omit the one you want removed. If I'm mistaken, then please add demonstrative code to your question. Thanks!

Comment: This needs more context. Are you talking about a single graphics device window? Or a part of the window? Created with `par(mfrow()`, or `layout()`, or are we talking grid graphics? Is this RStudio specific?

Comment: How is this question different from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66316880/3358272)? (Besides that one having reproducible code, that is.)

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly, you want to know how to influence the *RStudio IDE* to edit the *history* of plots it shows in its Plots *pane*, is that right? Since I suspect that it is just using R's dev history (available to us non-RStudio users), I don't think that partial-history is supported (and, though the ref is old, it is not a new question: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-April/160090.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this 3 plots:

```
plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg)
plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg, pch = 5)
plot(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$mpg, pch = 7, cex = 2)
```

In your plots tab you can achieve your task with:

1. Arrow red: Move to the plot you want
2. Arrow green: remove actual plot
3. Arrow blue: clean all plots.
   [image]

Comment: Exactly! Now I want to delete second plot but not by using the broom, but with command instead.

Comment: I have found `dev.new()` here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008264/how-do-you-delete-the-current-but-not-all-plots-in-the-rstudio-plotting-device> but was not able to do it by code!